# PHP - All subcategories of an aliment in multidimensional array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in PHP

Array:

```
$Hierarchie = array(
    ...
    'Agrume' => array(
        'super-categorie' => array(0 => 'Fruit'),
        'sous-categorie' => array(
            1 => 'Citron',
            2 => 'Citron vert',
            3 => 'Kumquat',
            4 => 'Mandarine',
            5 => 'Orange',
            6 => 'Pamplemousse',
            7 => 'Partie d\'agrumes'
        ),
        'Orange' => array(
            'super-categorie' => array(0 => 'Agrume'),
            'sous-categorie' => array(1 => 'Orange sanguine')
        ),
        ...
```

each aliment have `super-category` and `sub-category`, what I want is to have all `subcategories` of an aliment not only his own for example:
 `Agrume' I want as result an array with

```
(Citron' 'Citron vert' 'Kumquat' 'Mandarine' 'Orange' 'Pamplemousse' 'Partie d\'agrumes
```

and also subcategories of those subcategories ... until i reach the end recursively.

Comment: Sorry to ask but is *aliment* supposed to be *element*?

Comment: yes (Agrume, Fruit, Orange ....) and just to add I need a function that input an element and output an array with all it's subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

Filter recursively:

```
function array_filter_recursive( array $array, callable $callback = null ) {
    $array = is_callable( $callback ) ? array_filter( $array, $callback ) : array_filter( $array );
    foreach ( $array as &$value ) {
        if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
            $value = call_user_func( __FUNCTION__, $value, $callback );
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

$searchKeyword = 'Agrume';
$masterResult = array_filter_recursive($Hierarchie);
$subCategories =  $masterResult[$searchKeyword]['sous-categorie'];

print_r($subCategories);
```

[Output test here](https://rextester.com/KIAR19748)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but maybe i wasn't clear I actually want a function that output not only (Citron, Citron vert, Kumquat, Mandarine, Orange, Pamplemousse Partie d'agrumes) but also every subcategory of Citron, Citron vert... and subcategories of those subcategories ... until there is no subcategory left of a chosen element.